# Identifying overlapping lines within layer

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, vector-layer

I am trying to identify the overlapping lines within a layer that consists of polygons of land parcels.

I have already converted my data to lines and exploded those lines.
Indeed, I have run a `"no duplicates"` rule with the Topology checker and it identifies the overlapping lines (shown as red in the image below). But I do not know how to select the data identified by the Topology Checker.

When I run `"intersect"` on the layer, it seems to return all my data, including the non-overlapping portions. Is there any built-in tool that can help me here? If not, I assume this would be a straightforward SQL query?

[image: example]

Comment: Try running 'remove duplicate geometries' from processing toolbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I honestly don't know how to extract overlapping lines through the Topology checker. Let me suggest another tool - **SAGA: Shared polygon edges**,  which is available in the Processing Toolbox.

[image]

1. Activate **Shared polygon edges** tool from `Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Vector polygon tools`.
2. Select a unique id field in your polygon data (e.g. `"fid"` in this example).
3. Give a small Tolerance to ensure the tool recognizes all overlapping edges... you may have to give a trial and error... 1.0 meter worked for me in this case.
4. Tick on `Check vertices`
5. <kbd>Run</kbd> the tool.

You will then obtain a line layer **Edges**, which would look like below:

[image]

- I have changed the Edge layer style to green dashed line.
- Open the attribute table to examine which edge has come from which polygon(s).
- If you select any of the edge, corresponding attribute record will show id (`ID_A` and `ID_A`) from the original polygons to which the edge belonged.